# (android) Can I change whatsup status for code using?

Tags: android

Thank for all 
Can I change whatsup status for code using ??? 
How can I change whatsup status using Java code for Android ?

example :

Mystatus : Iam happy

how can i change status to "Good morning" for using eclipse (java code) ??

Thanks for all ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, I think you're talking about WhatsApp? Secondly, I don't think you're supposed to be able to do this. As long as WhatsApp does not offer an API for doing such things, you are not "allowed" to.

The possibility coming to my mind would be to "read" the outgoing XMPP messages sent by WhatsApp on changing the status, and simply copying them and send them on your own to the server, thus trigger a change of the status message. But this is - as far as I know - not allowed.